# Deserialization issue in OSGi

Tags: java, serialization, osgi, deserialization

I'm working with OSGi plugins and I'm facing problems with deserialization.

Say there are two plugins A and B. Plugin A is generic and would be used in a lot of applications, while Plugin B is specific to one application only. Plugin A is basically a framework for all applications. Plugin B uses Plugin A's API to persist state information. So, Plugin B depends upon A but A does not depend upon B.

To make it simple, assume that I'm storing the information in Plugin A's HashMap.  Class X, which implements Serializable is present inside Plugin B. Plugin A serializes it and stores. During the deserialization process, Plugin A is not able to find class X and it fails. I can't add Class X to Plugin A, since Plugin A is generic and doesn't make any sense in A.

Class X is available during runtime. What is the proper and clean way of solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like plugin A is a cache. Plugin A should be designed in the way that a classLoader can be passed in during the initialization (or during each request). If it is not designed in this way, it is not really OSGi friendly and it should not be used in OSGi environment.

E.g.: EHCache, Infinispan and other cache engines allow you to pass a Classloader instance during the initialization of the cache.

Comment: It's non-trivial to get an API which is not ClassLoader aware for bundle B, but I think it can be possible by implementing the cache as a service factory and then creating a new service instance for each bundle *X* requesting a cache. A service factory gets a reference to each Bundle requesting a service, so you could then wrap that Bundle's `loadClass` in your own ClassLoader impl which you then pass on to EHCache.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Fragment Bundle](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) for bundle A with Class X.